# When the user clicks on download I want the file to be downloaded in an x * y resolution

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

**When the user click on the photo is downloading the original photo ,
but what i want is;when the user clicks on download it should be downloaded on for example 400x400 resoulution.**

```
<a href="images/<?php echo $row['image_name'] ?>" 
class="ms-5" download><i class="bi bi-download" 
style="color: black; font-size:20px"></i></a>
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: `href="resample.php?image=images/<?php echo $row['image_name'] ?>"` and have the program do the conversion